# Busy Icon keeps running - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented a code to show a busy icon and this is it

```
angular.module("app", [])

    .controller('UploadCtrl', function ctrl ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.busy = false;

        $scope.submit = function () {
            $scope.busy = true;

            // pretend to make an http call...
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.busy = false;
            }, 10000);
        };
    });
```

This is the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Busy Runner</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-disabled="busy" ng-click="submit()">Submit <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="busy"></i></button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code the busy loader keeps running. Please what could be wrong.
This is the plunk I have made.
[view plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkSUDrA6jP4Y0nKvexe6?p=preview)

Comment: What's wrong? The spinner stops after 10 seconds as designed.

Comment: I want is triggered on button click. That was my motive.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you try to do. It starts the spinner when you click the button. What do you expect?

Comment: Take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/qkSUDrA6jP4Y0nKvexe6?p=preview

Comment: Also take a look: http://plnkr.co/edit/qkSUDrA6jP4Y0nKvexe6?p=preview. This is achieved embedding it in a controller. And it keeps spinning by default

Comment: Good Micheal. You are awesome. Please post an answer let me accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference a controller which not exists. Fix the HTML code

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="UploadCtrl">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module("app", [])

    .controller('UploadCtrl', function ctrl ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.busy = false;
```

In the above code you have name your controller as 'UploadCtrl' ,where as, in HTML file

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
```

controller is 'ctrl' , due to which it can't load the controller hence the angular part is not executed.

Change your app.js to

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {..}
```

View [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MGPmb2vwV3riSbqzwLkm?p=preview)

Also I removed ng-disabled from `<button ng-disabled="busy" ng-click="submit()">Submit` since you are already using  `$scope.busy = false;` as soon as script loads.

Checkout [ngController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) .